# How to distinguish '\7' from '\a' in Python3?

Tags: python, scheme

I'm writing a Scheme interpreter using Python and I have an issue parsing the special character literal (format -> "#\char-name") in Scheme. I need a way to distinguish the character '7' from the character 'a' when written in the above ('#\7' and '#\a') format.

I've found that

```
'\a' == '\7'
```

returns

```
True
```

in Python.

I need to parse the Scheme characters in the special format and return the characters, (here 'a' and '7') appropriately to be stored in a list for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\` so that Python doesn't decode it into a character. So rather than writing `'#\a'` write `'#\\a'`,. Consider that `'\\a' == '\\7'` is False. This is required for string literals in the Python code. But isn't needed for strings read from files.

Comment: It's Scheme code I'm trying to parse and it cannot be of the format #\\char-name but rather #\char-name

Comment: But you are clearly including that code as a string in Python code. If you read it from a file, no escaping would be required.

Comment: Reading from a file is definitely an option. +1

Comment: @AnandKrishna Think of it like if you were to read "\x" from stdin or a file it equals the python string "\\x" since python does escaping before storing it. When you're going to use your interpreter it won't use python strings as source but something read in which does not do escaping.

Comment: I understand the underlying concept but the issue is just with '\a' and '\7' since both have the same internal representation in python. I need a way to distinguish between them.

Comment: You could use a raw string: `r'\7' == r'\a'` is False.